# How to highlight background color of kendo grid row while dragging in angular?

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-draggable

**I want to highlight the background of the row while dragging in Kendo-grid Angular.
which CSS class should I use to change it on drag.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.k-drag-clue {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```